# How do I revert to the old highcharter interface?

Tags: r, highcharts

After updating my highcharter package to 0.5.0 (i.e., highcharts also updated to v5) in R, my highcharts now include four new buttons (for drawing circles, etc., onto the graphs). How do I get back to the old layout?

To supply a jkunst example,

```
library(dplyr)  
library(highcharter)  
data(stars)

colors <- c("#FB1108","#FD150B","#FA7806","#FBE426","#FCFB8F",
            "#F3F5E7", "#C7E4EA","#ABD6E6","#9AD2E1")

stars$color <- colorize(log(stars$temp), colors)

x <- c("Luminosity", "Temperature", "Distance")  
y <- sprintf("{point.%s:.2f}", c("lum", "temp", "distance"))  
tltip <- tooltip_table(x, y)

hchart(stars, "scatter", hcaes(temp, lum, size = radiussun, color =
color)) %>%  
hc_chart(backgroundColor = "black") %>%  
hc_xAxis(type = "logarithmic", reversed = TRUE) %>%  
hc_yAxis(type = "logarithmic", gridLineWidth = 0) %>%  
hc_title(text = "Our nearest Stars") %>%  
hc_subtitle(text = "In a Hertzsprung-Russell diagram") %>%  
hc_tooltip(useHTML = TRUE, headerFormat = "", pointFormat = tltip) %>%  
hc_size(height = 600)
```

leads to [image: this]

whereas it should look like the second example of:

http://jkunst.com/highcharter/showcase.html

I can get rid of the export-button with `hc_exporting(enabled = FALSE)`, but I don't know how to get rid of the four buttons.

Comment: I'm using  highcharter package to 0.5.0 in R 3.3.1. But without the four new buttons. Not sure of the highcharts version.

Comment: Strange. Be sure of the highcharter version do you have. If the problem persist try with the development/github version, or let's talk via github issues.

Comment: @jbkunst Thanks for taking your time. I have the most recent version. Error was caused by a change in the default options; see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the new buttons as default as well, but as per [documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/17/Annotations)  the `hc_annotationsOptions` controls the behavior of the new buttons:

```
hc_annotationsOptions(stars, enabledButtons = F)
```

should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses!

Error was caused by the line
`options(highcharter.chart = list(credits = list(enabled = FALSE)))`
which was run prior to the highcharts.

Two points:
- Line could be removed (credits seem to be disabled as default)
- It seems that changing one option in the new version messes with the other default options. Best new approach would be:

```
  hcopts <- getOption("highcharter.chart")
  hcopts$credits$enabled <- FALSE
  options(highcharter.chart = hcopts)
```

Comment: Yes, I need to create some (elegant/clever) way to change the defaults without override the others, (like `knitr::chunk_opt$set(... ...)`). Sorry for that! ;). Don't forget you can enable credits via `hc_credits`.